# Architecting support for marking susbtrings in text using Postgres, and attaching data to them

Tags: postgresql, architecture

I need to support "Post"-like structures that contain text, but substrings of that text can be "linked" to some data by the user.

*Example*:  "oh yes I ***know all*** about this"

Here the user marked the words `know all`, and linked it to some data that the user inserted (e.g - [date: __ , tags: _ , _ , media: ...]

The client implementation will be dependant on the architecture/implementation we choose using our Postgres DB.

**Also,** we would want to translate those posts and texts, which potentially linked/marked words in english for example can become one single word in another language.
e.g - "I have done" = "hice" in spanish. So relying on indexes is a bit problematic.

I thought of two approaches so far :

**1. Approach I** - Managing a list of indexes of highlighted text

`post_links_table :`

| post_id | indexes | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [9, 16] | {"data": 2/2/2022, "tags": [#abc, #def], "media": ....} |

However:

a. indexes - what if user edited the post, and erased the words or made the link shorter/longer. Is managing a list of such indexes is really the most efficient and easiest way to handle this use-case ?
Also, as I mentioned above regarding translation : "I have done" can become one word - "hice" in Spanish. So relying on indexes is a bit problematic.

b. data - what if in the future I would like to query (or with/by) the "data" details, a json column could prove problematic. Although - this probably could be tackled by normalizing the data column.

**2. Approach II** - separating the text into jsons parts.

For example, our example above would turn into

```
    [{"text", "oh yes I"},

    {"link", "know all" },

    {"text", "about this"}]
```

And then the "link" json could also contain some extra data the user inserted to that highlighted substring(s).

However, querying this post (by FTS or other querying) could prove to be inefficient.
Also, essentially this is just like managing a list of indexes. What if the user edited the post and the highlighted/linked parts?

Comment: On point 1 (which looks best IMHO) you ask " what if user edited the post, and erased the words"? Could you take the view that if they do that they will lose some comments and that's their choice?

Comment: not sure I understood your question, what I meant was that managing indexes isn't always easy, especially in editting modes.
Also, we would want to translate those posts and texts, so indexes can be misleading here because three linked words in english for example can become one single word in another language.

Comment: I don't get the problems with indexes. When user changes `oh yes I know all about` to `oh yes I know nothing about` you know that part of the link was changed. You either automatically modify beginning and/or end of the link or prompt user to specify what to do with the link (as in where it should start/stop in the modified text). Then the problem with translation. If the is some kind of relationship between words (that your program is aware of) in different languages then there is no problem in using that relationship to translate start/end indexes of the link.

Comment: If the no such relationship there is no way to automatically reuse the links defined in one language for the text in the other _regardless of the way you represent links_. If translation comes from user you would need to ask user to specify the place for the link in it. If it is done automatically I guess some review of the translation would be needed to mark the links there. And the last one, postgres allows quering by json fields so search is not a problem.

Comment: @RomanKonoval so would prefer to rely on maintaining indexes, or simply have a table which breaks the text into slices, similarly to approach 2, where we don't even need to know the indexes, but would result in big tables (one post can result in many many records)